# ¿Cómo puedo corregir el error de meditación Guru: Core 1 entró en pánico con interrupciones y SPI?

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

Estoy haciendo un pequeño programa que cambia una imagen en una pantalla TFT LCD de 0.96" cada vez que se presiona un botón. El problema viene que cuando presiono este botón hace la función que tiene que hacer pero instantáneamente la placa se apaga y aparece este error aparece en Serial He intentado poner la parte de la pantalla en una función diferente pero tampoco funciona.

```
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.

Core  1 register dump:
PC      : 0x403788bf  PS      : 0x00050731  A0      : 0x8037535d  A1      : 0x3fc940b0  
A2      : 0x00000004  A3      : 0x00018044  A4      : 0x000637ff  A5      : 0x3fc94090
A6      : 0x00000000  A7      : 0x3fc9293c  A8      : 0x3fc97104  A9      : 0x4037aaae
A10     : 0x00000001  A11     : 0x3fcf5640  A12     : 0x60004000  A13     : 0x3fc94070  
A14     : 0x00000000  A15     : 0x00000000  SAR     : 0x00000007  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c
EXCVADDR: 0x80375369  LBEG    : 0x00000000  LEND    : 0x00000000  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000  


Backtrace: 0x403788bc:0x3fc940b0 0x4037535a:0x3fcf5880 0x4200f97a:0x3fcf58a0 0x4037bc60:0x3fcf58c0

ELF file SHA256: fdf39c4ba55b369c

Rebooting...
␀�ESP-ROM:esp32s3-20210327
Build:Mar 27 2021
rst:0xc (RTC_SW_CPU_RST),boot:0x8 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
Saved PC:0x4202a006
SPIWP:0xee
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fce3808,len:0x44c
load:0x403c9700,len:0xbe4
load:0x403cc700,len:0x2a38
entry 0x403c98d4
```

Este es mi codigo:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <TFT_eSPI.h>

#include <Images.h>

#define DISPLAY_ENABLED
#define DISPLAY_WIDTH 80
#define DISPLAY_HEIGHT 160
#define DISPLAY_ROTATION 0
TFT_eSPI tft = TFT_eSPI(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT); // Invoke custom library

#define KEYBOARD_DISPLAY_SWITCH 10

//KEYBOARD_DISPLAY_SWITCH FN KEY
bool volatile WorkingAsKeyboard = true;

void IRAM_ATTR FNKeyboardDisplay()
{
    WorkingAsKeyboard = !WorkingAsKeyboard;
    delay(5);
    if(WorkingAsKeyboard)
    {
        tft.fillRect(KeyboardFN_display_image.x, 
                     KeyboardFN_display_image.y, 
                     KeyboardFN_display_image.width, 
                     KeyboardFN_display_image.height, 
                     TFT_BLACK);
        tft.pushImage(KeyboardFN_display_image.x,
                      KeyboardFN_display_image.y, 
                      KeyboardFN_display_image.width, 
                      KeyboardFN_display_image.height, 
                      image_KeyboardFN, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        tft.fillRect(DisplaydFN_display_image.x, 
                     DisplaydFN_display_image.y, 
                     DisplaydFN_display_image.width, 
                     DisplaydFN_display_image.height, 
                     TFT_BLACK);
        tft.pushImage(DisplaydFN_display_image.x,
                      DisplaydFN_display_image.y, 
                      DisplaydFN_display_image.width, 
                      DisplaydFN_display_image.height, 
                      image_DisplaydFN, 0);
    }
}

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);

    tft.begin();
    tft.setRotation(3);
    tft.setFreeFont(&FreeSansBold9pt7b); //Altura de la fuente 12
    tft.setTextColor(TFT_WHITE);

    pinMode(KEYBOARD_DISPLAY_SWITCH, INPUT_PULLUP);
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(KEYBOARD_DISPLAY_SWITCH), FNKeyboardDisplay, FALLING); //Function KEY Pushed (PullUp)
}

void loop()
{
    Serial.print("Program: ");
    Serial.println(WorkingAsKeyboard);
    delay(10);
}
```

Y la parte Images.h, la imagen es solo en blanco y negro y hay una estructura para establecer dónde se encuentra y el tamaño de la imagen para que funcione la función.

```
//Size: 480 Bytes 32x15 pixels
static const uint8_t image_DisplaydFN[495] PROGMEM= {
0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff
....
,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff
};

const struct KeyboardFN_display_image{
    const uint8_t x = 40;
    const uint8_t y = 5;
    const uint8_t width = 32;
    const uint8_t height = 15;
}KeyboardFN_display_image;

const struct DisplaydFN_display_image{
    const uint8_t x = 40;
    const uint8_t y = 5;
    const uint8_t width = 32;
    const uint8_t height = 15;
}DisplaydFN_display_image;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mueve la pantalla al void loop ya que no es conveniente que un ISR tenga delay ya que la idea es que sean lo mas rápido posible además si es con un botón puedes hacer el debonuce de otra forma aquí te dejo una posible implementación:

Te recomiendo leer https://www.gammon.com.au/interrupts

```
#define KEYBOARD_DISPLAY_SWITCH 10
#define DEBOUNCE_DELAY_FN 200

bool volatile WorkingAsKeyboard = true;
bool volatile interrupted_FN = false;
//millis var to debounce
unsigned int volatile last_interrupt_FN_time = 0;

void IRAM_ATTR FNKeyboardDisplay()
{
    unsigned int interrupt_time = millis();
    if (interrupt_time - last_interrupt_FN_time > DEBOUNCE_DELAY_FN){
        WorkingAsKeyboard = !WorkingAsKeyboard;
        interrupted_FN = true;
        last_interrupt_FN_time = interrupt_time;
    }
}

void loop()
{
//Check if keyboard is working as Display Mode or Keyboard Mode
    if(WorkingAsKeyboard && interrupted_FN)
    {
        tft.fillRect(KeyboardFN_display_image.x, 
                    KeyboardFN_display_image.y, 
                    KeyboardFN_display_image.width, 
                    KeyboardFN_display_image.height, 
                    TFT_BLACK);
        tft.pushImage(KeyboardFN_display_image.x,
                    KeyboardFN_display_image.y, 
                    KeyboardFN_display_image.width, 
                    KeyboardFN_display_image.height, 
                    image_KeyboardFN, 0);
        interrupted_FN = false;
    }
    else if(!WorkingAsKeyboard && interrupted_FN)
    {
        tft.fillRect(DisplaydFN_display_image.x, 
                    DisplaydFN_display_image.y, 
                    DisplaydFN_display_image.width, 
                    DisplaydFN_display_image.height, 
                    TFT_BLACK);
        tft.pushImage(DisplaydFN_display_image.x,
                    DisplaydFN_display_image.y, 
                    DisplaydFN_display_image.width, 
                    DisplaydFN_display_image.height, 
                    image_DisplaydFN, 0);
        interrupted_FN = false;
    }
}
```